# 68% Confidence level in multinormal distributions

Tags: confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis

I wanted to create some contour plot to give confidence level say at 68% and 95% of some 2-dim multivariate normal distribution. (later I will have to go to 3-dim). I was wondering whether there was some nice prescription in here like in the normal distribution that is given by 1sigma deviation, 2sigma deviation, etc. or shall I do numerical integration or similar ... I am a bit lost right now

Comment: For an example of how to do this in Excel, see http://www.real-statistics.com/multivariate-statistics/multivariate-normal-distribution/confidence-ellipse/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A $1-\alpha$ region ("interval") for a bivariate normal $N_2(\mu,\Sigma)$ is those $\mathbf x$ for which

$$({\mathbf x}-{\mu})^\top{\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\mu}) \leq \chi^2_{2,{1-\alpha}}$$

where $\chi^2_{2,{1-\alpha}}$ is the $1-\alpha$ quantile of the $\chi^2_2$.

More generally, a $1-\alpha$ region for a $p$-variate normal is those $\mathbf x$ for which

$$({\mathbf x}-{\mu})^\top{\Sigma}^{-1}({\mathbf x}-{\mu}) \leq \chi^2_{p,{1-\alpha}}$$

---

Edit:

@MånsT is quite right to bring up the possibility that you may have been estimating parameters; if that's the case, then indeed things change as indicated in his comment.

Comment: +1 And if $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is unknown but estimated by the sample covariance matrix $\mathbf{S}$, the region is given by a quantile of the F distribution: $\frac{n(n-p)}{p(n-1)}(\mathbf{\bar{x}}-\mathbf{\mu})^T \mathbf{S}^{-1} (\mathbf{\bar{x}}-\mathbf{\mu})\leq F_{p,n-p,1-\alpha}$.

Comment: Then, the quantile determines for any multivariate normal distribution the probability to expect some event in that region?
I mean, for a normal distribution, $\chi^2 = 1$ gives $1-\alpha = 68.27\%$. Does the same holds for any p-variate normal distribution? Maybe I didin get the idea ..

Comment: The quantile determines an ellipse which contains $1-\alpha$ of the probability in the bivariate case. In the trivariate case it generates an ellispoidal surface that contains $1-\alpha$ of the probability. That is a random observation from a $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ will lie inside those bounds with probability $1-\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, then what I have to do is to look for this $\chi^2$ value determining this quantile for some given p-value either in a table or some computer program where $\chi^2$ distribution is implemented if I understood propperly, sin't it?

Comment: Yes. For example, to enclose 95% of a bivariate normal with mean $(1,2)^\top$ and variance $\Sigma = \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0\\ 0&\frac{1}{2}
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, you find the values of $\bf{x}$ where $(x_1-1,x_2-2)\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&0\\ 0&2\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)(x_1-1,x_2-2)^\top \leq 5.99$, which is where $(x_1-1)^2 + 2(x_2-2)^2 \leq 5.99$, an ellipse in $(x_1,x_2)$ space.

Comment: Sorry, I see I started to respond to your first comment before your final edit of it; the 68% at 1 s.d. away from the mean only applies to a univariate normal.

Comment: @Glen_b Ok thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. Now it's perfectly clear for me how to find such a countour line. Thanks a lot! (Sorry for the delay, I was having lunch...)

So to sum up, in order to look for CL at some percentage (%) you just look for your $\chi^2$ value which gives you back the desired quantile as defined above. Perfect!